# Bootstrap 3 - Navbar collapses on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is an odd bug.  Each time I go to a new page by clicking a link in the navbar, the navbar will collapse and add a horizontal bar for a split second.

[image: horizontal scroll bar over top of navbar]

I have dug into some of the js and I think the class `.collapsing` is added for that short amount of time.  Here is what I found in the inspector.

[image]

Here is a link to the site: http://dev.apaxsoftware.com/

From there you can click through the pages on the navbar and see the issue.

Comment: if you change the `collaspe` class to `collasping` on the element where `id="navbar-collapse-1"` you can see it. It's actually a scroll bar. Did you modify the original boostrap CSS to change margins or padding on the classes relating to `nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the navbar links contain:

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` which was probably used to close the navbar after clicking on a link. A better solution is to use:

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in"` so that only the active link is targeted.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.